# how to get last part of pathname using useParams hook in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parameters

I'm trying to get the `param` part of this url: `http://myapp.com/123` using this code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log("id", id); // undefined. why??

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{id}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but somehow the `id` variable is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Configure a router, something like this, the 2 dots and an identifying word.
path="movie/:id" or path="movie/:nameurl". Check which version of dom router you are using, you should use version 6, I have read their documentation and help. With what I said above it should be solved.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import GenresPage from "../pages/genres";
import Home from "../pages/home";
import Layout from "../pages/Layout";
import Movie from "../pages/movie";

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="movies" element={<GenresPage />} />
          <Route path="movie/:id" element={<Movie />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```